# Why appear a validation error saying the date format is invalid?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a date field like:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
               name="date" value="{{ old('date') }}" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
$(".input-group.date").datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    minuteStep: 5,
    startDate: date,
});
```

To insert in db first I have this code to valdiate:

```
 'date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"',
```

Then to insert:

```
      'date' => (isset(
$request->date)) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->date) : null,
```

But even if the user introduce a date using the datetime picker it shows always a validation error saying that the format of the date is invalid. Do you know why?

The "`dd(date('d F Y - H:i'));`" shows "22 July 2018 - 18:37" (shows in en).

The "`$request->all()`" shows "date" => "22 Juli 2018 - 19:50" (shows in german).

Comment: Your computer's locale doesn't match the server's.  Pretty common problem for international sites, I wouldn't recommend accepting a month name because of it.

Comment: Thanks, but is necessary to store in DB the month. The column date is of type datetime.

Comment: I didn't say don't accept a month, I said don't accept a month name.  Month numbers are what you store in the database and thus be that much easier to handle on the server.

Comment: In line with @Devon, you could use `d m Y`...so the month's number gets stored instead.

Comment: Thanks, but so is necessary to use d m Y both in the server but also in the jquery datetimepicker code?

Comment: I change the jquery format to "dd-mm-yyyy - hh:ii" and in server validation to "j-m-y - H:i" but same issue, it says that the format is incocrrect.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  'date' => (isset(
  $request->date)) ? Carbon::parse('Y-m-d h:i:s', $request->date) : null
```

to insert into `database`